# NSJSONSerialization misbehaves, 98% of the time returns array, other 2% returns dict

Tags: ios, json, nsjsonserialization

This is really very odd.

We're accessing a json Twitter API that always returns an array.
ie
https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/485963081.json

We do:

```
if([NSJSONSerialization class]) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&error];    
        DLog(@"JSON Parsing Error: %@", error);

    } else {
        NSString * jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        jsonResponse = [jsonString JSONValue];
    }
    if([jsonResponse count] > 0) {
        NSString *jsonText = [[jsonResponse objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"text"];
        twitterText = jsonText;
    }
```

This works a vast majority of the time. The rest, we get this:

```
[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Note, all the errors are on iOS5, so the SBJSON library does not apply.

Sometimes NSJSONSerialization parses the array as a dict. Which frankly, is not possible using the data from twitter. So what's happening here?

Comment: Maybe you got an error response from Twitter? If you get this behaviour, can you log the JSON data?

Comment: Right - so test the class if([jsonResponse isMemberOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) and if this is true log the JSON.